# Why do old questions bump on the top when there was only a slight modification?

Tags: discussion, editing, specific-question

I understand that when a question recieves a brand new answer it bumps on the top. But there have been multiple cases of questions that bumps on the top just because someone fixed 3 misspellings in the answers.

This is very annoying because it tricks me into thinking that either the question or one of its answer is new, when this is not the case.

The question in question is [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6354/has-the-world-ever-seen-pure-communism), although I have been tricked by such things several times. The last edit dates form 6 monts, why does it bump on the top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wasn't an edit to the question that bumped it; it was an [edit on one of its answers](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/6355/revisions).

Edits on questions and answers bump the threads to allow the community to review the changes. It can be a bit disappointing when what you thought was new activity turned out to be a couple of minor fixes, but even a minor edit could be problematic or otherwise worth our attention. We don't want to let an edit introducing obscenities (for example) staying around for long.

Comment: Yeah, for major edits, it makes sense, but if it's just literally a couple of capitalization changes, who cares?

Comment: @Bregalad I don't disagree, but I don't have high hopes SE will be convinced in changing the current bumping behaviour. You might be interested in upvoting this related feature request on the central Meta: [Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122567/allow-non-bumping-minor-edits-but-review-them-on-review)

Comment: Ok I've registed in SE Meta just to upvote this. It's not specific to Politics, but it's an extremely annoying practice that people change like 2 letters in an answer to a closed question and it bumps everything at the top. If at least it was an open question and the edit was substantial it would make sense

Comment: Maybe we should trust established users to be able to make minor edits without review. Call it a new "Privilege" you get at 1000 rep so you can check a "minor edit" box that will allow edits less than 50 characters to be applied without bumping.

Comment: @SurpriseDog Only way that'd work is if it were like how wikipedia handles it, where there's a list of minor edits. Which makes it quicker for mods to see things that are either: not minor edits, or just regular abuse. (i.e. saying something's a minor edit should attract more mod scrutiny, but need less mod work)