# Non-edits push the question into the reopen queue. What to do about it?

Tags: discussion, editing, reopen

[This question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/10839/revisions) got pushed into the reopen queue with [two](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/30136) [non-edits](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/30194).

Hitting the Leave Closed button is not a big deal, but it is strange that the system allow such (non-)edits.

**Q: Non-edits push the question into the reopen queue. What to do about it?**

Comment: Related: [How to deal with tiny edits intending to raise a question's visibility for the purposes of extra rep?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4198/28994)

Comment: Only the first qualifying edit within 5 days of closure should push the question into the reopen queue. The question's two additional times in the reopen queue were almost certainly the result of actual reopen votes. Given that the question has > 100 views, the reopen votes would have expired after 4 days. Thus, a moderator would need to look at the timeline to verify that reopen votes were cast.

Comment: @CDJB thank goodness I did not vote to reopen in the queue.  Or else I would have been review-banned.

Answer (score 4):

The "non-edits" you have linked to are actually edits, and this auto-reopening nomination [works as intended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue).

What reviewing users can do (in general) is reject *trivial* edits, especially to closed questions. I too often see users approving edits here that are no real improvement. Sometimes, this has no real downsides, but sometimes it does. Besides the closed-question-auto-reopening-nomination issue, such edits also [bump the question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4356/is-it-possible-to-put-date-time-limits-on-answering-editing-old-questions/).

I realize it's not possible to reject the OP's own trivial edits. And the trivial edits you have linked to are actually of this kind, i.e. they are the question-asker's own trivial edits. I don't see a good solution for this using the current toolset short of mods locking closed questions in response to the OP's trivial edits... which is probably iffy/controversial.

Luckily there's a 5-day expiration timer on most closed questions, beyond which edits usually don't trigger a reopen nomination, unless the question is "popular" as decided by a somewhat unclear SE algorithm (which was being "tuned" according to the [years old] meta-SE discussion). Interestingly enough, the closed question
that triggered this meta-post was probably of this kind: it was posted in 2016 (!) but [trivially] edited a few days ago (March 15). The question does have a +7 answer though (despite being closed), so I think that triggered the "popular" exception to the usual 5-day limiter. The [published rules say](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078):

> On September 6th, 2013, the automatic triggers for putting questions into the reopen queue changed. They were tweaked repeatedly over the years and, as of December 20th, 2019, a closed question will automatically be added to the reopen queue when it is...
>
> 1. ...Edited (body edits only) within 70 days of closure by the author. Or,
> 2. ...Edited (body edits only) within 70 days of closure by a 3rd-party, provided the editor has not also flagged the question or voted to close it. Or,
> 3. ...Sufficiently popular, where popularity is calculated based on question score, top answer score, or views per month. We're still tweaking the exact thresholds for these.

Note that unlike for reopen-nomination, there doesn't seem to be any question-age check for edits (trivial or otherwise) triggering a bump to the "active" questions list.

---

There's one "mysterious" aspect about that question, namely what triggered the 2nd review, as there were two recent reopen reviews actually.

[image]

The March 15 one was clearly triggered by the immediately preceding edit, but it's not clear (to non-moderators) what triggered the 2nd review. As was [explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345363/why-did-an-edit-to-a-closed-question-apparently-trigger-two-reopen-reviews) to me on the big-meta

> Unless you are a moderator, not all sources of triggers are visible in the timeline.

> Reopen reviews can also be triggered by someone casting a re-open vote directly on the post. Since that’s a vote to reopen these are not shown in the timeline for anyone below moderator level. Someone almost certainly tried to reopen that post directly from the post itself here.

> There is an [open feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277132/show-close-and-reopen-votes-in-the-timelines-daily-votes-summary) to add daily summaries of close and reopen vote counts to the timeline.